# Series indicating third weekday in a month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I would like to create a pandas Series that indicates whether a certain date - which is supposed to be the index of the Series - is a third friday in a month.

My idea is to create the Series first with zeroes as values and then changing those zeroes to ones where the index is a third friday in a month. This is my approach which seems to work.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# 8 years of data
dates = pd.date_range("2010-01-01","2017-12-31")

# create series filled with zeroes over those 8 years
mySeries = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(dates)),index=dates)

# iterate over series and change value to 1 if index is a third friday in a month
for index,value in mySeries.iteritems():
    if index.weekday() == 4 and 14 < index.day < 22:
        mySeries[index] = 1

# if the sum of the series is 96 (1 third friday per month * 12 months * 8 years) then the solution should be correct
print(sum(mySeries))
```

I would be interested to see other and easier solutions as well of course.

Comment: You can rollback my edit if you don't like it, but I believe the question is now better suited to this website :)

Comment: How working my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use non loop faster solution with [`weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html) and [`day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day.html), convert boolean mask to `int` with `Series` contructor:

```
dates = pd.date_range("2010-01-01","2017-12-31")

days = dates.day
s1 = pd.Series(((dates.weekday == 4) & (days > 14) & (days < 22)).astype(int), index=dates)
print (s1.sum())
96

print (s1.head())
2010-01-01    0
2010-01-02    0
2010-01-03    0
2010-01-04    0
2010-01-05    0
Freq: D, dtype: int32
```

**Timings**:

```
In [260]: %%timeit
     ...: mySeries = pd.Series(np.zeros(len(dates)),index=dates)
     ...: 
     ...: # iterate over series and change value to 1 if index is a third friday in a month
     ...: for index,value in mySeries.iteritems():
     ...:     if index.weekday() == 4 and 14 < index.day < 22:
     ...:         mySeries[index] = 1
     ...: 
The slowest run took 5.18 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 2.68 ms per loop
Compiler time: 0.31 s

In [261]: %%timeit
     ...: days = dates.day
     ...: s1 = pd.Series(((dates.weekday == 4) & (days > 14) & (days < 22)).astype(int), index=dates)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 603 µs per loop
```